# Set project stage keys by values or variables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an item in DB.

```
{ _id: 1, key: 'some_key', value: 'some_value'}
```

I need in aggregation framework set in project stage query like this:

```
Item.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    key: '$value'
  }}
])
```

And get this result:

```
{_id: 1, some_key: 'some_value'}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Aggregation Pipeline.

Pipeline stages used are [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

Below is the Query used to get the result

```
 db.a.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      arr: [
        {
          k: "$key",
          v: "$value"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      newAttrs: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$arr",
            as: "pair",
            in: [
              "$$pair.k",
              "$$pair.v"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            _id: "$_id"
          },
          "$newAttrs"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Sample Data used:

```
{"_id":1,"key":"some_key","value":"some_value"}
{"_id":2,"key":"my_key","value":"my_value"}
{"_id":3,"key":"test_key","value":"test_value"}
{"_id":4,"key":"new_key","value":"new_value"}
```

Result obtained:

```
{"_id":1,"some_key":"some_value"}
{"_id":2,"my_key":"my_value"}
{"_id":3,"test_key":"test_value"}
{"_id":4,"new_key":"new_value"}
```

The